# App Inventor - Best way to alphabetize a list of Names

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am learning to use App Inventor building simple apps.

I came across this practice project, in which the app takes three names and alphabetize them below in a label. Ideally, it will also make the first letter of both first and last names capital no matter how the user input.

I've achieved the basic function， but I feel that my way was awkward and time-consuming. I would like to know if anyone has a better alternative. The more advanced function, i.e. auto-capitalization function, I am having a hard time of thinking of a way to do it.

Attached are my coding blocks and app interface. Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: sorry for the previous screenshot that was incomplete, I've updated the code block screenshot to show the full blocks.

[image: App Interface]

[image: Code Blocks]

Comment: [How to sort a list using the webviewer(!)](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2sort) Btw. don't hesitate to [do a search in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/sort%7Csort:relevance) to find other sort solutions

Comment: @Taifun thanks! So is it safe to say that without using webviewer but only the compare text function in the App Inventor, it has to be complicated like shown in my screenshot? (I've updated the code block screen to the right file so that it now shows full picture).

Comment: No. It does not looks like you followed my recommendation to *do a search* in the forum, else you would have found solutions, which use lists...

Comment: I did find Saaj's tutorial and am going to give it a try. Thanks @Taifun

Answer (score 1):

Just tried building from the start with an alternative method I found by [saj](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-sorting-on-app-inventor/). Works great, especially for a list that's much longer than 3 items! Just going to need to figure out a way to capitalize the last name if present. Hope this may help anyone in the future.

[Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VV5j.png)

Answer (score 1):

[image: bubble sort]

Use a bubble sort as shown in the picture and when comparing each item use to uppercase to compare them while they are all Uppercase. The sort will rearrange the list and you just print out the list in either a label or list view elements.  I used the latter.

Answer (score -1):

**For Auto-capitalization:**

In your layout set `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` in your `EditText`.

**OR**

Programmatically: you have to include `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` in the `setInputType` method of the `EditText` like below

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)
```

**For sorting (alphabetize) list of Names:**

```
Collections.sort(list)
```

For case sensitive custom Comparator should help like below.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

Or if you are using Java 8:

```
list.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Ohh sorry... didn't see that :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort though! I'm sure when I move beyond using the App Inventor to code your answer would help a lot.